# jQuery appendTo div within a div with a unique id

Tags: jquery

I want to append certain elements to a div within another div with a unique id.

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="49617" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all">
    <h2 class="ui-collapsible-heading">
    </h2>
    <div class="ui-collapsible-content" aria-hidden="false"></div>
</div>
```

The parent div `data-role="collapsible"` has an id which is dynamic. The child div `ui-collapsible-content` is created by the framework am using. How can I add elements into this div at the click of a button.

This is my jQuery code below, the variable stopId is the id for the parent div. It appends to the parent div but not to the desired child div.

```
$("<h2 />").text("Buses Due").appendTo("#" + stopId);

$.each(data.arrivals, function(i,item){

  $("<span/>")
  .text(item.estimatedWait)
  .attr("class", "busListing time")
  .appendTo("#" + stopId);

  $("<span/>")
  .text(item.routeName + ' to ' + item.destination)
  .attr("class", "busListing info")
  .appendTo("#" + stopId);

  $("<br/>")
  .appendTo("#" + stopId);
});
```

Comment: Be careful. An unique identifer (ID) has to start with a letter. ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")...but browsers are very forgiving ;)

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are asking: `appendTo("#" + stopId + " > .ui-collapsible-content");`

Comment: @SirDerpington that's not the case for HTML5

Comment: @billyonecan you're right! I'm sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.appendTo("#" + stopId + ' > .ui-collapsible-content')`

Ex:

```
$("<h2 />").text("Buses Due").appendTo("#" + stopId);

var el = $("#" + stopId).children('.ui-collapsible-content');
$.each(data.arrivals, function(i,item){

    $("<span/>")
    .text(item.estimatedWait)
    .attr("class", "busListing time")
    .appendTo(el);

    $("<span/>")
    .text(item.routeName + ' to ' + item.destination)
    .attr("class", "busListing info")
    .appendTo(el);

    $("<br/>")
    .appendTo(el);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure why you're using ("#" + stopId). It makes more sense to just set stopId to the parent div, not just the id. When you append, you can set the context of where the selector is found with $('child', 'parent'). So you would do something like...

```
.appendTo('.ui-collapsible-content', parentDiv); // parentDiv = "#" + stopId
```

Basically, this finds .ui-collapsible-content within parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.appendTo($("#" + stopId).children('ui-collapsible-content'));
```

Comment: I would have used `.children` instead of `.find`